# Modify Visual C++ vcvars32.bat to target XP Platform

Tags: visual-c++, boost

I found a post from Stack Overflow user Eoin, showing how he modified vcvars32.bat for VC++ 2012 (I use 2013):

```
:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_;%CL%
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion
```

Here is my section before modification:

```
:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion
```

After applying the modification above, I built a 'hello world' application **using CL** (cl main.cpp) but the executable does not run on Windows 2003.  If built **using the IDE** with the option mentioned, it runs just fine.

Can someone shed some light as to what is happening?

P.S.  The reason for wanting to do this is that **I need to build the Boost libraries using the XP Platform option** to allow my application to run on Windows 2003.  There is not a solution or a project available to build Boost and this is done through the command line using their Bootstrap and Bjam routine which does not have an XP Platform option.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that Stack overflow Eoin had suggested was accurate except that his answer did not contain a necessary setting for %LINK%

Here is my working :x86 section:

```
:x86
if not exist "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat" goto missing
call "%~dp0bin\vcvars32.bat"
set INCLUDE=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Include;%INCLUDE%
set PATH=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Bin;%PATH%
set LIB=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\7.1A\Lib;%LIB%
set CL=/D_USING_V110_SDK71_;%CL%
set LINK=/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.01 %LINK%
goto :SetVisualStudioVersion
```

I hope that people creating solutions that need XP and Windows 2003 compatibility find this useful.

Full details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx?PageIndex=2